# zoom works on windows but nit ipad

Tags: css

I am using this code to zoom out whole page, and it works fine for PC:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 990px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  {

html 
{
    zoom: 0.8; 
}
}
```

But I can't get it working on iPad no matter what. I tried many stuff like:

```
@-o-viewport {
    zoom: 0.8;
}
```

Any idea, what else I might be missing, to get it working on iPad same as on PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [CSS-Triks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/):

> Zoom is an old IE thing. **It isn't something you should use on live sites.** If you want to scale content, use [CSS Transforms](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/). You can also use [filters](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) if you need oldIE support.

Note it was *an old thing* in 2013.

Comment: Hmm, google search showed me that 'zoom' is supported on all browsers, except Opera, so I thought it is ok to use it. Well, I could use scale transform, but it does not work for downscale like zoom does. Zoom just makes everything looks smaller, but fits into the page. While scale leaves white space on all sides. Is that somehow specific to the way my css is coded?

Comment: [Can I use `zoom`?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom) Note the `Resourses` tab under the table, where you will find all the information you need about this CSS property, allowing you to take an informed decision about whether to use it or not in your project. I thought I'd point you to the relevant information, but feel free to read all the documentation and decide what is relevant and what not yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Using scale may be an alternative to zoom.

```
transform: scale(0.8);
```